# How can I create a file that is accessible by other applications on Android/iOS device using ngCordova File plugin?

Tags: file, email, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am working on an application that is building on the IONIC platform and is intend to run on both Android and iOS platform.

One function in this application is to send an email to an user specified address. A text based file that contains application generated data will be attached with email.

For example, use may use this application to do some experiment and generate some test data. The data will be saved in 'report.csv' file somewhere on the device and then send it out as email attachment to user.

I use ngCordova's file plugin to generate this file and use ngCordova's email composer plugin to draft email.

However, I realised that the ngCordova's email composer plugin can only populate a draft email content and has to rely on third party applications to send email out. This bring up an issue as the file generated by my application is always saved in a private accessible area.

The third party email application cannot access the file to attach it with the email.

So, here comes my question: is there a way to save a file in a 'public' area via ngCordova file plugin so that it can be accessed by multiple applications?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you already tried the different **device paths** mentioned in the [ngCordoca docs](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/)?

Comment: @Beat Hi Beat, many thanks for your comment and suggestion. I did not try other device paths except the 'cache' directory and the 'tmp' directory mentioned in that document. I guess one reason that I didn't try all of them is the 'private' column in the documentation lists all of these directories as 'yes' (private). The only exception here is that all external paths (SD Card) on Android device are public. However, using external storage (SD Card) doesn't quite fit into my requirement. Anyway, many thanks for your comment.